# file.write can't save int

Tags: python, save

I am building a save system for a game im making, im trying to save all of the resources you get in the game so you can load into it the next time you play. I was going to use file.write as I saw it being used in other types of games, but it cant save the variables as ints. Is there any sort of workaround or just a different sort of saving that I could use to be able to do this?

```
from Resources import *

def start_new():
    Q = int(input('which save file do you want to save to? 1, 2, or 3.'))
    if Q == 1:
        file = open("save1.txt", "w")
        file.write(Manpower)
        file.write(Food)
        file.write(Food_Use)
        file.write(Wood)
        file.write(Farmers)
        file.write(Food_Income)
        file.write(FarmNum)
        file.write(MaxFarmer)
        file.write(Deforestation)
        file.write(Trees)
        file.write(Tree_Spread)
        file = open("save1.txt", "r")
```

Comment: what kind of data does this variables(Manpower, Food...) have?

Comment: first of all, you should close the file before re-opening it, In addition, I would suggest using context managers to do it it should look like that:

`
with open(filename,mode) as f:
    f.write(whatever)
`

Comment: You could save all the variables as a CSV file, or put them in a dictionary or list and save as JSON.

Comment: @Bhargav they are integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert integer values to string. You can do this using several method. Lets write `Manpower`(Assuming type of this variable is `int`) to file to be an example:

A small advice, there is no need to call file.close() when using with statement. The `with` statement itself ensures proper acquisition and release of resources.

```py
with open("save1.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(Manpower))
```

or even better:

```py
with open("save1.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(f"{Manpower}\n")
```

`\n` is `EOL`(End Of Line) character. After `EOL` character, new writes will be in next line. You can use it to separate and identify values while reading them again.

Comment: if i convert it to a string wouldnt i not be able to use math/use it as a int? how would i convert it back?

Comment: @PinkPit You can convert string to int using `int(var_name)`.

Answer (score 0):

On you code you need to close the file after make changes...

```
file.close()
```

Your code:

```py
from Resources import *

def start_new():
    Q = int(input('which save file do you want to save to? 1, 2, or 3.'))
    if Q == 1:
        file = open("save1.txt", "w")
        file.write(Manpower)
        file.write(Food)
        file.write(Food_Use)
        file.write(Wood)
        file.write(Farmers)
        file.write(Food_Income)
        file.write(FarmNum)
        file.write(MaxFarmer)
        file.write(Deforestation)
        file.write(Trees)
        file.write(Tree_Spread)
        file.close()
        file = open("save1.txt", "r")
        # stuff
        file.close()
```